# posix threads (pthreads) standard

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix, standards

I'm looking for the `pthreads` standard for some work I'm doing on parallelism. I have found that it is supposed to be IEEE 1003.1c "EEE Standard for Information Technology--Portable Operating System Interface (POSIX(R)) - System Application Program Interface (API) Amendment 2: Threads Extension (C Language)".

However, when [I get to it](http://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1003.1c-1995.html), it says that the standard has been "superseded", but they don't say by what (or I failed to see where they do say it). What is the link to the superseding standard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been superseded by a newer edition (2008). It's available as IEEE 1003.1-2008 or ISO/IEC 9945-2009 (for enough money) or [The Open Group Single Unix Specification, version 7](https://www2.opengroup.org/ogsys/jsp/publications/PublicationDetails.jsp?publicationid=12310) (for free). All three have identical content.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's a very old document. What you probably want is the full [POSIX 2008 spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged Linux in your question, I recommend that in addition to what Jerry Coffin answered, you look at the Linux [pthreads man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pthreads.7.html).  The current Linux pthreads implementation (NPTL) is not exactly POSIX conformant; there are small details that are handled differently.

There are also extensions like the `__thread` keyword (to designate per-thread variables, much simpler than `pthread_key_create()`; explained in detail for [GCC here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Thread_002dLocal.html)) that are available in Linux and other operating systems, and are likely to be included in POSIX at some point in the future.

If you are doing extremely performance-sensitive work, I recommend you also look at the atomic built-ins and vector extensions available in GCC, ICC, and Pathscale compilers ([GCC vector extensions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html), [legacy `__sync` builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html), [C++11-style `__atomic` builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html), and [x86-specific builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/X86-Built_002din-Functions.html)). While these are not standardized yet, they are available in aforementioned compilers, and aside from the recent `__atomic` builtins, have been available for at least a decade. From personal experience, I can attest that these facilities can provide a significant performance boost (~40% in a classical molecular dynamics simulator I'm working on), while still being portable between non-Windows systems and compilers.